# Unable to satisfy constraints error in UIWebView playing video

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I'm using ionic/angular and cordova and playing video using the HTML5 video tag, though in Xcode I'm getting the following error(s) when playing the video. The error appears after I have hit play for the second time. So in effect, PLAY -> DONE -> PLAY -> ERROR.

Though whilst it throws an error the video plays as expected and nothing appears to go wrong, but I have no idea what this error means in the context of ObjC so if anyone could tell me if its worth worrying about?

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd69150 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fbfcdf8a510.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7fbfcde9ad80.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd477a0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbfcde996c0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fbfcdf8a510 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd477f0 H:[UIView:0x7fbfcde996c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fbfcdf8a510 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd473b0 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7fbfcde9ad80]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfcde46fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd479c0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7fbfcde9ad80]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfcde46fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd47ad0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbfcde46fb0]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fbfcde47c80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd478b0 H:[UIView:0x7fbfcde46fb0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fbfcde47c80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdcaa410 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7fbfcde49c30'Done'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfcde996c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdcab350 H:[AVButton:0x7fbfcde49c30'Done']-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fbfcde7c370'0:03'](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdcaab20 H:[UILabel:0x7fbfcde7c370'0:03'(55)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdcdbf20 H:[UILabel:0x7fbfcde7c370'0:03']-(6)-[AVScrubber:0x7fbfcde98ff0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdcdbf70 AVScrubber:0x7fbfcde98ff0.right == UILabel:0x7fbfcde52ba0'\U200e-0:43'.left - 6>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdc84860 UILabel:0x7fbfcde52ba0'\U200e-0:43'.right == AVButton:0x7fbfcde3f680.left>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdc848b0 H:[UILabel:0x7fbfcde52ba0'\U200e-0:43'(59)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdcdbfc0 AVButton:0x7fbfcde3f680.right == UIView:0x7fbfcde996c0.right - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcd90eda0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fbfcde47c80(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbfcdd477f0 H:[UIView:0x7fbfcde996c0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fbfcdf8a510 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: those are just apple warnings and it's their fault, they are harmless and there is nothing you can do to avoid them.